# Resume video using Jquery(Html5 video element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I am using video html5 element to get the duration property to find the last time
where the video stops playing either when user closes browser or user pauses, to send it to the database so that later it will resume from where it stops.

Currently what I googled and check on stack overflow is something like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $("#video").on("durationchange", function() {
         alert("Current duration is: " + this.duration);
     }); 

  </script>

 <video id="video" poster="image.jpg" controls>     
      <source src="video_path.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
```

I also want to seek to the video to the duration where the user stops after login
to my app. I tried it but is not correct way of doing

```
       $(window).load(function() {
       .ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/api/videoResume/",
            data: param = "",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"              
        })
        .done(function(result){
           //update the video element duration 
           //seeking video to the duration
        })
   });
```

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = video.onpause = e => 
 postToYourServer(video.currentTime)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it just add an event listener, so that when a video is paused, you can capture the current time and you then instead of sending an alert like in the example below, you could send that information to your database etc. The code would look like this:

Javascript:

```
var video1 = document.getElementById('video1');

function videoPausePlayHandler(e) {
    if (e.type == 'pause') {
   alert(video1.currentTime);
    }
}

video1.addEventListener('pause', videoPausePlayHandler, false);
```

HTML:

```
<video id="video1" poster="image_path.jpg" controls>
<source src="video_path.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/l33tstealth/qr72bvxb/1/